# jQuery press keyboard key on interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought this would be simple, but I can't figure it out.

I want to simulate `keypress` on some keyboards keys (i.e, the arrows), on a time interval.

So this is what I've done :

```
var typer = function(){             
    var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
    var keys = [37,38,39,40];
    var key = keys[Math.floor(Math.random()*keys.length)];
    e.which = key;              
    $(document).trigger(e);
    console.log(e);                 
};
setInterval(typer, 500);
```

FYI, the log returns :

```
jQuery.Event {type: "keypress", timeStamp: 1395335870282, jQuery20002915873059537262: true, which: 37, isTrigger: 3…}
```

Any help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the event first.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/E53s8/

```
$('body').keydown(function(e){
    var keys = [37,38,39,40];
    if( $.inArray(e.which, keys) != -1 ) {
        alert('Arrow keys pressed');
    }
});

var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 38;
$('body').trigger(e);
```